# MySql check oldest record against current record with nested queries

Tags: mysql, self-join, subquery

My head is spinning trying to figure out the SQL query I need to use.  I have tried a variety of nested queries and self joins and everything is failing me.  I assume I am WAY over thinking it.

Basic idea:  I have a single table, let's call it `OrderTable` and there are four (relevant) fields in the table: `OrderId`, `CustomerId`, `RestaurantId`, `OrderTime`

When a customer places an order, the date/time stamp is added to the `OrderTime` field.  The other three fields are just integers, with the `OrderId` field as the primary key (and auto-increment).

I am trying to write a query that will return a list of `CustomerId` records where the first record (earliest date) for that customer is a specific date (let's say '2012-03-14') and the RestaurantId is a specific number (let's say 29).

At the moment i have what i can only assume is an overly complicated way of doing it.  Also, i currently get an error "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" when there is more than one record matching my subquery.

Can anyone help me with a more elegant solution?  Thanks!

CURRENT QUERY:

```
SELECT `CustomerId` 
FROM `OrderTable` 
WHERE `OrderTime` LIKE '%2012-03-14%' 
AND `RestaurantId`='29' 
AND `OrderId`=(SELECT `OrderId` 
   FROM `OrderTable` 
   WHERE `RestaurantId`='29' 
   GROUP BY `CustomerId` 
   ORDER BY `OrderTime` ASC
   )
```

Comment: Not clear: `return a list of CustomerId records where the first record (earliest date) for that customer is a specific date (let's say '2012-03-14') and the RestaurantId is a specific number (let's say 29).`

Comment: even if the `OrderTime` is not the but but assumes it is order on the same date, the customerID will always appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: John Totet Woo was probably right on this one, but still refer to the second part of my post to avoid the LIKE clause :)

I might be slightly confused on what you're asking for, but if you change the subquery from '=' to IN, do you get what you're after?

```
SELECT `CustomerId` 
FROM `OrderTable` 
WHERE `OrderTime` LIKE '%2012-03-14%' 
AND `RestaurantId`='29' 
AND `OrderId` IN (SELECT `OrderId` 
    FROM `OrderTable` 
    WHERE `RestaurantId`='29' 
    GROUP BY `CustomerId` 
    ORDER BY `OrderTime` ASC
)
```

What was mostly bothering me though, is that you can use

```
AND DATE(OrderTime) = '2012-03-14'
```

Instead of the LIKE

Comment: This did it.  All i needed was "IN" rather than "=".  I have also updated the DATE portion so that it does not use LIKE.  Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, evidently I was unclear in my understanding of your question.  I was almost positive, after reading other answers, that I had misinterpreted.  If you're absolutely positive that my answer is correct, I will remove my "irrelevant" markings.

Comment: Yes...as far as i can tell from very basic testing, your two parts have completely resolved this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your current can return multiple values. The `=` sign need only one value from your subquery and in order to do that, you need to limit the values of your subquery by using the `LIMIT` keyword.

```
SELECT `CustomerId` 
FROM   `OrderTable` 
WHERE  `OrderTime` LIKE '%2012-03-14%' AND 
       `RestaurantId`='29' AND 
       `OrderId`= (
                     SELECT `OrderId` 
                     FROM `OrderTable` 
                     WHERE `RestaurantId`='29' 
                     ORDER BY `OrderTime` ASC
                     LIMIT 1
                  )
```

you can also do it this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM OrderTable
WHERE OrderID IN
(
    SELECT  OrderID
    FROM    OrderTable 
    WHERE   RestaurantID = 29 AND
            DATE(OrderTime) = DATE(2012-03-14)
) b
```

the **simpliest** solution among all is this:

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT CustomerID
    FROM    OrderTable 
    WHERE   RestaurantID = 29 AND
            DATE(OrderTime) = DATE(2012-03-14)
```

Comment: This is not accounting for needing to know if that was their FIRST order ever...though it does solve the issue of multiple returned values from the subquery.  The reson for the subquery is to determine if this was the first ever order for this customer...  If it was not (or if their other order was a different RestaurantId, then they do not get returned in my results)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm confused. Why can't you just select all the records that equal your OrderTime and Restaurant ID like this?

```
SELECT * FROM OrderTable WHERE OrderTime = "2012-03-14" AND RestaurantID = "29";
```

Would that not give you the list you want?

Comment: I need to know if this is the FIRST TIME that the customer placed an order...so i have to get the orders for that date, and then compare that to the first order ever from that customer (which might have been a different restaurant...in which case it is NOT in the result set)